# Is There a Version If Neo4J that works without Internet Connectivity?

Tags: neo4j

I’m working on an isolated network with no internet connectivity. The new Desktop Version seems only to work if it can connect back to the mothership.

Is there a way to configure this so it can work without an internet connectivity or, if not, is there a download accessible of the last version before they added this ‘feature’?

Comment: What does not work for you in that scenario? I have Neo4j Desktop 1.0.18, and a Project DB running neo4j version 3.3.3 Enterprise, and I am able to start the Desktop and the DB and run queries from the Browser.

Comment: Without internet connectivity it doesn't complete launch. It seems in launching it needs to check externally.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop may download java, then the != server versions, and the plugins.

It is not a replacement of the previous downloads, it is a tool for helping devs organize on their workstation.

Just get the tarball and eventual plugins needed. Install them, no need for internet (I imagine guides like :play movies wont work)